# Download Firebase Storage folder to a Cloud Functions Temporary Folder

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download the entire folder from Firebase Storage so I can zip those files and upload them back to Firebase Storage while generating a download link.

I have read a lot of posts and code but everything seemed getting away from my scope.

Do you have a clear example on how to download a Firebase Storage Folder to a Cloud Functions Temporary Folder or at least some hints on I could do it, keeping in mind that I am targeting a specific folder?

Comment: Use the nodejs SDK for Cloud Storage to 1) list the files at the folder of interest, 2) iterate them, 3) download each one separately. There is no bulk download operation provided by the SDK.

Comment: Thanks Doug for your reply. So far I was unable to list files at a specific folder. I tried to use something like firebase.storage().reference("folderName") and it failed. Won't work. I just found examples on how to detect changes in a bucket but these won't help for my specific problem at the moment for iterating over a specific folder and list files to download them one by one and add them to a temp folder.

Comment: Use this: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles

Comment: So I have a Storage.storage().ref("folderName") snippet. How would I target that path with this api?

Comment: That won't help.  You'll need to call getFiles using the description it provides for itself.

Comment: I only have the url to the storage. bucket from api takes an object. I tried with // admin.initializeApp({
//     credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
//     storageBucket: standardBucket,
//   }); and gave storageBucket the refference name but it did not work

Comment: I think it worked. I just set the bucket to const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('storageUrlFromFirebase'); and It returned me a pretty long json. Can you please post your tip as an answer so I can at least vote for it?

Comment: Doug will ya post your tip in form of an answer so I can vote it ?

Comment: There is no bulk download option. So you can use for loop to iterate and download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bulk download operation provided by the SDK.  The general pattern for downloading all files with some shared prefix using the node SDK for Cloud Storage will be:

1. [list the files using getFiles](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) at the prefix (folder) of interest
2. iterate them
3. download each one separately